# Django CBV method to output HTML from a different CBV

Tags: python, html, django

Is there a way to create a method within one class based view that has the ability to output the HTML of another class based view when called?

The psuedo code would look something like this:

```
class View1(ListView):
  def method(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return   # template.html output from View2

class View2(ListView):
  ...
  # normal ListView
```

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to send an HTML email.  I have a CBV set up that returns the contents of the email, and then would like to make this callable from EmailMessage as the "subject" argument.  Sorry for not being clearer on this.  So View1 contains an EmailMessage.  Where I thought the code would look like: EmailMessage(subject=View2.as_view()), but this didn't work as planned.  Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't use django view, to create html body for email. For this purpose you can use `render_to_string`. Read more about it here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#the-render-to-string-shortcut

Comment: Thank you guys for your help.  I used a both or your solutions and it worked.  I used the reder_to_string to call the template.html, and then I used the EmailMultiAlternatives from Burhan because I had initially set it up in EmailMessage which only accepts plain text in the body of the email.  Cool Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet that you can use:

```
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.template import Context
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

def send_template_email(context, # variables for the templates
                        plain_text, # plain text template
                        html_part, # html template
                        subject, # the email subject
                        recipients, # a list of recipients
                        from_addr):

    plaintext = get_template(plain_text)
    html_part = get_template(html_part)
    ctx = Context(context)
    text_content = plaintext.render(ctx)
    html_content = htmly.render(ctx)
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject,text_content,from_addr,recipients)
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content,"text/html")
    msg.send(True)
```

Call it from your view (or anywhere) like this:

```
plain_text = 'plain-text.txt'
html_part = 'html-email.html'
recipients = ['user@email.com']
from_addr = 'admin@domain.com'
subject = 'Your email'

variables = {'name': 'John Smith'}

send_template_email(variables,
                    plain_text,
                    html_part,
                    recipients,
                    from_addr,
                    subject)
```

`plain-text.txt` and `html-email.html` should be somewhere in your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` locations, these are normal django templates so, `plain-text.txt` can be:

```
Dear {{ name }},
   All you bases are belong to us!

Love,
--
Robot Overload
```

and `html-email.html`:

```
<p>Dear {{ name }},<br />
   All your bases are belong to <strong>us!</strong>
</p>
<hr />
<p>Love,<br />Robot <em>Overlord</em></p>
```

Comment: Burhan, I put a comment above in @mariodev's comments.  Thanks for your guys' help.  I got it working!